# Number of C characters

Tags: c

How many total characters are present in C language character set?
What does "f" stands for in `printf()` and `scanf()` functions?

Comment: @OmG  Hmmmm.  The 16 functions in "c11 7.21.6 **Formatted** input/output functions" section all end with `f`.  Most other functions do not end in `f`.

Comment: I guess that "too broad" in this case is the inclusion of an unrelated question about standard library function naming. @Marie Try moving it to another question. SO is a Q&A site so, to maintain its effectiveness, we like specific questions with definitive answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a table of all the characters for every C99 Character Set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902771/where-can-i-find-a-table-of-all-the-characters-for-every-c99-character-set).

Comment: It is also unclear what you are asking.  There is a defined character set that may be used to represent C source code (i.e. the set C code may be written in), but there is no "_C language character set_" in terms of what a C program may output on a _display_; that is platform dependent.  http://aboutc.weebly.com/c-character-set.html

Answer (score 2):

> What does "f" stands for in printf() & scanf() functions?

format.

The C library function `int printf(const char *format, ...)` sends formatted output to `stdout`.

The C library function `int scanf(const char *format, ...)` reads formatted input from `stdin`.

> How many total characters are present in C language character set?

It depends on your coding system. If UNICODE, then it is really a large set.(for e.g. UTF-16 is about 0x0 to 0x10FFFF, with some reserved empty spots).

If you are talking about ASCII, it is 0 to 127, and extended ASCII, is 128 to 255.

Comment: 1. Not all character sets that are called Extended ASCII have 256 codepoints. 2. All encodings for the Unicode character set encode all the codepoints (U+0000 to U+10FFFF) so there is no need to single out UTF-16. Also, UTF-16 code units only range from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF, it's just that some are used in pairs to encode codepoints > U+FFFF.